# this.props seems to be undefined and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to React js and I'm trying to do something very simple, when a user types into the text-input the text in the p tag on top of it should change as the user is typing. Here's the relevant code:

index.js

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'

var Name = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {name: ''}
},
changeName: function(event) {
    this.setState({
        name: event.target.value
    });
},
render: function() {
    return (
                <div>
                    <p>Your name is: {this.state.name}</p>
                    <App setName={this.changeName} />
                </div>
            )
    }
});

render( (<Name />), document.getElementById('content'));
```

App.js
    import style from '../style/base.scss';

```
export default function() {
    return (
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text!" className="fancy" onChange={this.props.setName} />
                </div>
    );
}
```

I thought this would work, but instead nothing gets rendered to the page at all. When I check the console on the browser, it tells me: "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**". This must mean that the "this" object is undefined but I can't think of a reason why. I didn't use es6 class syntax so I thought that "this" would work fine. Can someone tell me what's going on? Thank you in advance for anyone willing to look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using App.js as a stateless functional component. They don't have `this`. Instead the props are passed as an object parameter to your function. You could fix this by either accepting an object (such as `props`) in your function and accessing `props.setName`, or you could pull it out with destructuring and define your function like this: `export default function({ setName }) {` and then referencing `setName` instead of `this.props.setName`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that actually, but how do you recommend I pass the App.js the props object? I have to do it from my index.js so maybe I'm being stupid here, but what could I do? Thanks a lot though!

Comment: You already are passing the App component the `setName` property by doing this: `<App setName={this.changeName} />` The only issue was that you weren't accepting the props in App.js because you had an empty parameter list for your functional component.  You need to add a parameter which will then hold the props you are already passing.

Comment: Oh wow... Ok yeah, you were totally right, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks a lot man.